# How do I append elements to an empty html file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

For example if I have an html file which is just

```
<html>


</html>
```

and I have something like

```
const div=document.createElement('div');
```

How would I append the div to the empty html file? 
I have tried doing document.appendChild(div), but that did not work.

Comment: Where are you running your Javascript?

Comment: Instead of  `document.appendChild(div) `, try use `document.documentElement.appendChild(div)`

Comment: You have a huge mistake there. How is the browser going to know what to display if you don't have the <body> tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get Html element by selector query and apend the div

```
const div = document.createElement('div');    
const htmlElement = document.querySelector("html");    
htmlElement.appendChild(div)
```

Or just:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');  
document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
```

document.documentElement get the html element

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

we can do stuff like i.e: `myNav.append(EL_logo, EL_list, EL_btn)`.
Here's a concept I like really much by using a reusable Element constructor:

```js
/**
 * Create new Element helper
 * @param {String} tag Element TagName selector
 * @param {Object} attr Element attributes
 */
const EL = (tag, attr = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), attr);
```

## Append Elements to DOM

```js
const EL = (tag, attr = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), attr);

const EL_h1  = EL("h1", {
  textContent: "Hello, World!"
});

const EL_btn = EL("button", {
  textContent: "Click me!",
  type: "button",
  style: "color: blue;",
  onclick() {
    alert(this.textContent);
  }
});

document.body.append(EL_h1, EL_btn);
```

### Grouping using DocumentFragment

and appending DocumentFragment

```js
const EL = (tag, attr = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), attr);

const EL_a = EL("div", {
  textContent: "Some DIV Lorem ipsum"
});

const EL_b = EL("div", {
  innerHTML: "dolor <b>sit amet</b>"
});

const DF = new DocumentFragment();
DF.append(EL_a, EL_b); // Append to DocumentFragment first
// Here you can still manipulate DF using i.e: DF.querySelectorAll('div');

document.body.append(DF); // Append DocumentFragment
```

### Elements from Array

```js
const EL = (tag, attr = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), attr);

// Prepare UL Element
const EL_ul = EL('ul');

// Function for LI Element
const EL_Li = (textContent) => EL('li', {
  textContent,
  onclick( evt ) {
    console.log(this.textContent);
  }
});

const DF_list = new DocumentFragment();
const items = ["Click me!", "Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor"];
items.forEach(item => DF_list.append(EL_Li(item)));
EL_ul.append(DF_list);

// Finally append the UL element somewhere
document.body.append(EL_ul);
```

- [Object/assign *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [ParentNode/append *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)
- [DocumentFragment *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)